Ubuntu 24.04 not wake up after lock screen
Today I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on dell latitude 5490, but I discovered a problem.
After pressing the Super+L key combination, my screen goes dark, and I can’t wake up the laptop even though the power button light is still on.

I’ve tried pressing various keys on the keyboard, but the laptop remains unresponsive. I have to hold down the power button for 5 seconds and restart the machine.
I've tried disable TPM or secure boot or enable usb wake in bios.
I've tried edit /etc/default/grub, changing the line:


GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

To

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rdrand=force"

And

sudo update-grub

Then reboot, but it's not working
My current setting:

Dim Screen: On

Screen Blank: Never

Automatic Power Saver: On

Automatic Suspend: 15 min

Power Button Behavior: Suspend


Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Please help me, thank you very much.

any help from these options? https://pupuweb.com/how-fix-ubuntu-screen-lock-issue-sometimes-cant-turn-back-on/
